# Enter Database Administrator Account Information (Oracle Database Mobile Server)

Tags: database, mobile, oracle11g

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYrmQ.png) [image]

I am trying to install Oracle Mobile Database Server, when installation reaches "Enter Database Administrator Account Information", i get error as shown in image above (attached).

I am supplying it with SYSTEM username/password for Oracle Database 11g. I can login with that in server i.e. ... /localhost:1158/em/ , Installed Oracle 11g, GlassFish Successfully as per prerequisites for Oracle Mobile server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Oracle Mobile Database server, i gave bad installation connection settings with 11g server.

Note to New DMS Users: Oracle DMS is in extremely early stages, with lack of documentation/community support. Don't use it as yet to develop database driven synchronization applications with any mobile platform.